# 0-1 Knapsack - Dynamic TopDown-Recursive Approach in C#

Tags: c#, recursion, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

Hello I am trying to solve the classical Knapsack problem, but so far I only managed to implement the naive recursion which works from my perspective and yields the right results:

```
    static int[] objValue;
    static int[] objWeight;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        objValue = new int[] { 0, 11, 8, 4, 12, 4, 6, 9, 10 };
        objWeight = new int[] { 0, 4, 2, 2, 5, 6, 3, 5, 7 };
        int objNumber = objWert.Count() - 1;
        int maxWeight = 12;
        Console.WriteLine(Knapsack(objNumber, maxWeight));
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
    public static int Knapsack(int i, int w)
    {
        if (i == 0 || w==0)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        if(objWeight[i] > w)
        {
            return Knapsack(i - 1, w);
        }
        else
        {
            int case1 = Knapsack(i - 1, w);
            int case2 = objValue[i]+Knapsack(i - 1, w - 
            objWeight[i]);
            return Math.Max(case1,case2);
        }
    }
```

So far so good thats pretty much the basic algorithm itself, even though i get confused with the indexes sometimes. It works .... but now my dynamic approach:

```
    static int objNumber;
    static int maxWeight;
    static int[] objValue;
    static int[] objWeight;
    static int[,] costTable;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        objValue = new int[] { 0, 10, 5, 7, 12, 8, 6};
        objWeight = new int[] { 0, 6, 1, 2, 5, 4, 3};

        objNumber = objValue.Count()-1;
        maxWeight = 10;

        costTable = new int[objNumber+1, maxWeight+1];
        for (int i = 0; i <= objNumber; i++)
        {
            for (int w = 0; w <= maxWeight; w++)
            {
                if(i==0||w==0)
                { costTable[i, w] = 0; }
                else
                costTabelle[i, w] = -1;
            }
        }

        int result = Knapsack(objNumber, maxWeight);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
    public static int Knapsack(int i, int w)
    {
        if (costTable[i, w] != -1)
        {
            return costTable[i, w];
        }

        if (i<=0||w<=0)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        if(objWeight[i] > w)
        {
            costTable[i,w]=Knapsack(i - 1, w);
            return costTable[i, w];
        }
        else
        {
            int case1 = Knapsack(i - 1, w);
            int case2 = objValue[i]+Knapsack(i - 1, w - 
            objWeight[i]);
            costTable[i,w]= Math.Max(case1,case2);
            return costTable[i, w];


        }

    }
```

As you can see I only added a little bit of code to save all the correspondig nodes/possibilities. However it seems I made a mistake somewhere, maybe with the return function or one of the indexes, because my costTable looks like this:

[image: LUT for knapsackproblem]

There should not be any -1 in the table as far as i understood the algorithm. I hope you can provide me with some insight, looking into this since 12 hours and can not find the mistake!

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, there is no mistake at all. Apparently in your implementation, the initial value of `-1` in the state table represents a value of negative infinity (this works well as all values in the input are nonnegative and the recurrence relation uses maximization of values). These values remain in the table where a state is not examined in the recursion, which might be the case.

That being said, the implementation you use is not *really* [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) but [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization), as you use a recursive implementation and bound its running time by storing known state values in a lookup table. However, it is a it difficult to technically draw a line between the notions.